# How code changes take affect immediately with docker-compose?

Tags: angular, mean, nestjs

I'm new to MEAN applications and currently working on a project. I have included both Front and Back end to a docker container. Application is build and run on a docker with no probs. My problem is when I want to perform changes in the code in both front and back.

Any changes performed are not taking place immediately. I read a couple of articles of how to do it but it was not very clear to me, probably the ones I've read. Please find below some data from my current project.

[**Backend dockerfile**]

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node:10.16.0-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN adduser --disabled-password app
COPY ./* ./
RUN chown -R app:app /opt/app
USER app
RUN npm install
CMD [ "npm","run", "start:dev" ]
```

[**Front dockerfile**]

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node:10.20.0-alpine AS builder
RUN apk add --no-cache git=2.24.3-r0 \
    --repository https://alpine.global.ssl.fastly.net/alpine/v3.10/community \
    --repository https://alpine.global.ssl.fastly.net/alpine/v3.10/main


COPY . ./app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install
RUN ng build --prod --aot
# RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --aot

# FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
# COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 4200
#CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
# EXPOSE 80 443
# CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

[**docker-compose.yml**]

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    evillio-backend:
        build:
            context: evillio-backend/
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'

    evillio-frontend:
        build:
            context: evillio-frontend/
        ports:
            - '4200:4200'
```

[**Backend package.json**]

```
"start": "node dist/main.js",
    "start-local": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
```